# How to call a JavaScript file inside a PHP if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, php, html, chart.js

I have to call different JavaScript files depending on the users choice from a dropdown menu.

I tried to do it like this:

```
if ($subject == "Chemistry") {
  '<script src="ChartJS_Chemistry></script>';
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Any advice on how to activate the right file depending on the dropdown menu choice?

Comment: You forgot `echo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, you did not `echo` anything out.

But also your syntax is wrong:

```
'<script src="ChartJS_Chemistry></script>';
```

You're missing `"` and I am assuming you're also missing a file extension?

It should be something like:

```
echo '<script src="ChartJS_Chemistry.js"></script>';
```

Also; this is not best practice. Close your PHP tag then write the script tag in HTML:

```
<?php if( true ) { ?>
  <script src="ChartJS_Chemistry.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

Since then you'r not mixing your PHP with HTML - not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

your file path is broken, if your file is ChartJS_Chemistry.js

Call like.

```
if ($subject == "Chemistry") {
    echo "<script src='ChartJS_Chemistry.js'></script>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($subject == "Chemistry") {
        //close php tag here 
?> 
   <script src="ChartJS_Chemistry"></script>
<?php //start php tag again here
}
```